# Program to generate all the possible paths from one node to the other

Tags: python, graph, nodes

I wanted to generate all the possible paths from one node to the other with this program:

```
graph = { "a" : ["b","c"],
      "b" : ["a", "d"],
      "c" : ["a", "d"],
      "d" : ["e"],
      "e" : ["b"]
     }

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
        for newpath in newpaths:
            paths.append(newpath)
    return paths


print(find_all_paths(graph, "b","e"))
```

But unfortunately I get the Error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'newpaths' referenced before assignment

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what will be the value of `newpaths` when node is in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but this seems clear. In your function `find_all_paths()`, in your for loop, you are calling newpath before it exist. I would suggest to declare newpath here

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
      newpaths = []
      path = path + [start]
```

It should work

EDIT:
As DarryIG suggest, indent 2nd for loop is also working and probably safer than my solution

Comment: This could create erroneous results.  The fix is to ident the 2nd for loop so it is after the assignment of newpaths. Otherwise, if `if node not in path:`  is False, you could still iterate over `for newpath in newpaths:` using newpaths that was created from a previous node.

Comment: Effectively, didn't tought of that

Answer (score 0):

```
graph = { "a" : ["b","c"],
      "b" : ["a", "d"],
      "c" : ["a", "d"],
      "d" : ["e"],
      "e" : ["b"]
     }

path =  []
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path):
    global newpaths 
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for x in newpaths:
                paths.append(x)
    return paths
```

there you go, you need to set the variable as global before use it.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for the global declaration.  It only confuses things since the reader then is looking for a newpaths at global scope which doesn't exists.  The fix was just to indent the inner for loop inside the if statement.